# Php form in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

How can i use a simple php form in zend framework.

I am new to this framework,so please explain in detail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use normal HTML forms. Some code snippets for your controller:

```
// Get all params (Notice: including URL params)
$this->getRequest()->getParams();

// Get single param
$this->getRequest()->getParam('paramName');

// Check if post
$this->getRequest()->isPost();
```

Answer (score 1):

See e.g.

- [Zend Form Quick start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html) at the official Zend Framework documentation
- [Simple Zend Form Example](http://akrabat.com/tutorial/simple-zend_form-example/) from Rob Allen's Blog

Comment: I don't want to use the zend_form but i wish to use the simple html form.How to do this

Comment: @Ankhur Why not simply output some form HTML then? What do you need the Zend Framework for at all?

Comment: Means without using zend form ,you are saying that it will be somewhat not using the zend framework properly and actually wasting it

Comment: @Ankur not necessarily, but your question doesn't make much sense yet to me. What do you mean by a "simple form"?  I think you need to explain in more detail what you are doing with the Framework and what exactly your question is.

Comment: I am using the zend framework in the usual prescribed manner but i want to use simple html form in place of zend form.So i wish to know how to integrate this form with the zend framework

Comment: @Ankur Sorry, I don't know enough about ZF's MVC concept to answer that. I suppose, though, that you would integrate it just like any other piece of HTML.

Comment: But the usual zend form validation and other methods will they work in the usual manner?

Comment: @Ankur I don't know, sorry! I doubt that they will work as usual without some tweaking, though.

Comment: You can't use Zend Form to validate the form if you aren't using Zend Form. You can however use Zend_Validate components (which Zend Form uses anyway), so I would suggest you check those pages in the manual, that should give you a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Just create your form like you would normally but in your view file (index.phtml for example).
It will work. Nothing special to do just open a `<form>` tag and start coding.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me a lot At the beginning:

http://www.zendcasts.com/zend_form-introduction-part-1/2009/02/

http://www.zendcasts.com/zend_form-introduction-part-2/2009/02/

You should use Zend Form (not PHP form), it should be standard except in some special cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use plain html forms you should at least consider [Zend_Filter_Input](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html) for filtering/validation the userinput.

```
$filters = array('body' => array('StringTrim' , 'StripTags'));
$validators = array('body' => 'Alpha');

if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    // display form;
    return;
}

$input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $this->getRequest()->getParams());

if (!$input->isValid()) {
    // failed validation
    $this->view->messages = $input->getMessages();
    // redisplay form and show error messages
    return;
}

// form is valid, values are filtered 
echo $input->body
```